# How do I unselect a radio button and re-select the default button on click?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Basically I want to have three radio buttons. The first is selected by default. You click the second and it becomes selected. But if you click the second one again, after it is already selected, I would like it to instead re-select the the first. The same behavior for the second one would also apply to the third.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! It seems that several of them produce the desired results, but is there any benefit in opting to use one method over the other?

Comment: You have to figure which is best for your application. Factors like functionality, maintainability, and readability matter. In addition, others visiting the page might know what might have been the better solution. Also, its a convention (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the radio button `onclick` event function logic to arrive at the required functionality:

```
<p>Select your choice:</p>
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="val" value="1" onclick="app(this.value)">
    <label for="choice1">First</label>
    <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="val" value="2" onclick="app(this.value)">
    <label for="choice2">Second</label>
    <input type="radio" id="choice3" name="val" value="3" onclick="app(this.value)">
    <label for="choice3">Third</label>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

*app.js*:

```
var radio2Counter = 0;
var radio3Counter = 0;

function app(selectedVal) {

    switch(selectedVal) {
        case '2':
            radio3Counter = 0;
            if (++radio2Counter == 2) {
                document.getElementById('choice1').checked = true;
                radio2Counter = 0;
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            radio2Counter = 0;
            if (++radio3Counter == 2) {
                document.getElementById('choice1').checked = true;
                radio3Counter = 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            // console.log('Radio 1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution (no metter how many checkboxes do you use, this code will work):

**js:**

```
var curr = '';
var prev = '';

$('input').on('click', function(){

  if( curr == $(this).attr('id') ){

    if( prev != '' ){

        $("#"+prev).prop('checked',true);

        prev = '';

    }

    return;

  }

  prev = curr;

  curr = $(this).attr('id');

});
```

**html:**

```
<input id="rad1" value="1" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" value="2" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="rad3" value="3" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad3">Radio 3</label>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/wrfx9zpb/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can select the radio button using css and perform any styles over there

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="rad3" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad3">Radio 3</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to accomplish your requirement.

```
function CheckDefault()
{
if(this.checked){ document.getElementById('rad1').checked=true;}
}


<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="radio" name="rad" onclick="CheckDefault()"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="rad3" type="radio" name="rad" onclick="CheckDefault()"/><label for="rad3">Radio 3</label>
```